# How can i hide the image path on hover using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

Any one who know the answer please give me the suggestion to do this. I am using mozilla firefox browser, When i hover the image i get the url path of where it is located(left bottom of the mozilla)
 Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Is it possible to hide the href path.
Any suggestion would be great.

Comment: I guess you get an enlarged version when you click the image? Only hovering links will show a path in the bottom left corner.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? is it an aesthetic thing or security issue?

Comment: And I can right click on the image and get the path. Hopefully you are not trying to hide the url for "security"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the status bar shows the href destination, you can remove the `href` attributes onload and call window.location onclick instead: (jQuery):

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href]').each(function() {
        var href = this.href;
        $(this).removeAttr('href').css('cursor','pointer').click(function() {
            window.location = href;
        });
    });
});
```

Note that I added `cursor:pointer` to make it behave like a link even without the `href` attribute. The very same technique is often used on mobile web sites to prevent mobile safari to drop down it’s address bar when navigating through ajax.

Another more clumsy way would be to add a placeholder div on top of the anchor that grabs the anchor’s href and navigates using window.location onclick.

Either way, a quick look in the source or in a console would reveal the destination anyway.

Comment: your answer is the same as mine

Comment: No its not. You didn’t mention that the href can be removed using javascript without changing the HTML. Also, you didn’t mention the placeholder technique, used by f.ex Flickr. I think these are useful alternatives for the OP. If you are going to downvote, don’t do it based on your personal opinion.

Comment: I really wish SO had an ignore option to mute ppl like you.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you remove href attribute, and add onClick = "location('your url')" it will hide the href path.
for example:

```
<script>
function changeLocation(url){
   window.location.assign(url);
}
</script>
<a onClick = "changeLocation('http://www.w3schools.com')">Link</a>
```

Comment: Events should always be lower case "onclick" instead of "onClick"

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by calling on click method that opens image url in browser (url stored in `data-href` instead of `href`):

http://jsfiddle.net/mattydsw/TYSnB/

```
<a data-href="http://somewhere.com">new</a>

$('a[data-href]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = $(this).data('href');
});
```

**EDIT**

But also whole rest of "standard" behavior will be lost, e.g. open in new tab, copy link, search engines crawling.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have got already one answer for that, but if you want to open in new popup/window on click then it's fine but if you want to open in same page then what happen? also if you have use master page and on click of link like this new page load on content place holder area than what happen?

I have one of solution if you like.

We can use system.webrouting.routecollection in global.asax page for hide all or any page, 
 See below example:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {      
        RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes);
    }

void RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.Clear();
        routes.MapPageRoute("page1", "dir1/{country}/{State}", "~/page1.aspx");
}
```

It would be helpful to you.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I do this for pure html and js/jquery not asp

Answer (score -1):

```
<a onclick="window.open('http://whatever', '_self');"><img bla bla bla ></a>
```

EDIT : Note that it maybe not be great for referencing as this is not a natural way to do a link, robots won't crawl through it.