# Remove Anchor URL Label

Tags: html, url, hyperlink, anchor

I wonder if someone can guide me on how to remove the url label that appears at the bottom of the page when you hover over an anchor (I wonder if it's even posible). I've googled a lot and didn't find any answers.
Suppose I have

```
<a href="www.somepage.com" title="The Page">Link< /a>
```

in the bottom of the page there will appear a tooltip/label showing "www.somepage.com".

Please see here for an [example](http://cl.ly/image/2A1J1A1h0l17)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use jquery to hide the link as outlined here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655573/how-can-i-hide-the-image-path-on-hover-using-javascript-or-jquery]

Comment: [check this](http://superuser.com/questions/239202/turn-off-the-link-hover-statusbar-in-google-chrome).

Comment: Why do you want to hide this information? It's very useful for the user to know where a link goes, and helps with user-education about avoiding phishing scams. I can't think of any legitimate reason to hide the status bar text.

Comment: It's mainly for aesthetic reasons. Though I did thought about not hiding it because of what @Dai said. I wonder if it's even good practice because of the search engines…

Comment: By the way, it worked perfectly @pschueller.

Comment: @Adrián SEO is another reason not to do this: search engine spiders do not execute javascript, so they won't be able to follow your links at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either Javascript or JQuery.

For example, you can set to A attribute "href=#" and add an attribute url=www.somepage.com something like this:

`<a href="#" url="www.somepage.com" id="link">Link</a>`

If you click over this nothing happen.

Now, you need to apply with javascript or JQuery click event.  The next example is using JQuery and Javascript:

At the bottom of page's body:

`<script>`

`$('#link').click(function() {`

`var url = $(this).attr('url');`

`window.location.href=url;`

`});`

`</script>`